# How to replce a specific line in a file with Perl script

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a file test.txt that contains 80 lines.
In a perl script I want to replace the 60's line for example with an other one.

```
#!/var/www/cgi-bin/rootperl -w
my $path="/var/www/cgi-bin/test.txt";
open(FICH,">>",$path) || die("Ouverture impossible");
my @input = readline();
chomp(@input);
print FICH "@input[0]\n";
print FICH "@input[1]\n";
print FICH "@input[2]\n";
```

How can I replace a specific line (line 60 for example) by `@input[0]`? Example

```
@input[0] = "abcd";
```

And line 60 was `"SSID=test"` I want it to be `"abcd"`

Comment: You are aware, I hope, that you are not reading from `test.txt`, you are appending to it. And you are reading lines from STDIN into `@input`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$input[59] = $input[0];
```

after reading the input file and before writing to output file.

Note: the way to access an element in an array is `$input[n]` and not `@input[n]`

Have a try with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @input = readline();

my $file = 'path/to/file.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading: $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;

$lines[59] = $input[0]
open my $fh, '>', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for writing: $!";
print $fh @lines;
```

Comment: input is a table containing three variable!i want to write the first variable $input[0] in the file i opened "test.txt" at the 60 line..hope i was clear

Comment: @user2478348 Your question is very unclear. The problem is probably very simple, but the way you phrase it makes it pretty impossible to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
perl -i -pe 'if ( $. == 60 ) { print whatever;}' filea.txt
```